# Automorphisms of the adeles of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: automorphism-group, adeles

Consider the adele ring of the rationals $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}}$. Does any permutation of the set of valuations define an automorphism of this ring or must it fulfill some stronger property?

Comment: You are asking if $\Bbb{Q}_p\cong \Bbb{Q}_q$ or $\Bbb{R}$ for some $q\ne p$ ??

Comment: You must be misunderstanding something, please show us how you construct $\Bbb{Z}_p,\Bbb{Q}_p,\Bbb{A_Q}$.

Comment: I don't know the considered constructions. All that I know is that the ring of adeles is the restricted product of the completions of the field of the rationals, and indeed my goal is to show that such a permutation preserves the valuation.

Comment: The compltions (the $\Bbb{Q}_p$ and $\Bbb{R}$) are non-isomorphic. An element of $\Bbb{A_Q}$ is a "function" $v\to x_v\in \Bbb{Q}_v$, it doesn't make sense to permute the valuations. For $\Bbb{A_{Q(i)}}$ it is different because this time there are pairs of isomorphic completions (completion at $(2+i)$ and $(2-i)$ each isomorphic to $\Bbb{Q}_5$) that we can permute.

Comment: Yes, I know different completions are not isomorphic. So an automorphism of the adele ring necessarily preserves the valuation?

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/372349/are-there-infinitely-many-l-rigs?r=SearchResults. My goal is to prove that an automorphism of $\mathcal{M}$ corresponds to the preservation of the adele ring of the rationals, as it should map an automorphic representation of $\operatorname{GL}_{n}(\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}})$ to a similar automorphic representation. The key point being that the symmetry group of a given L-function be either of order $2$ or trivial.

Comment: I think $Aut(\Bbb{A_Q})$ is the restricted product of the $Aut(\Bbb{Q}_v)$ and $\sigma \in Aut(\Bbb{Q}_v)$ is continuous because $a$ is in $p\Bbb{Z}_p$ iff $(1+a)^{1/n}\in \Bbb{Q}_p$ for all $p\nmid n$ which implies that $Aut(\Bbb{Q}_p)$ is trivial, $Aut(\Bbb{R})$ is trivial because $a\ge 0$ iff $a^{1/2}\in \Bbb{R}$, so that $Aut(\Bbb{A_Q})$ would be trivial. But you said you don't know the constructions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117304/discussion-between-sylvain-julien-and-reuns).